# Let $H, K\le G$ be finite subgroups. If $|H|$ and $|K|$ are relatively prime, show that $H\cap K=\{e\}.$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I'm a little stuck on a question from a textbook that I'm self-studying group theory from, and could use a little bit of help.

Let $G$ be a group containing finite subgroups $H$ and $K$. If $|H|$ and $|K|$ are relatively prime, show that $H \cap K =\{e\}. $

At this point, the concepts of cosets and Lagrange's Theorem have been introduced, but nothing else like the Sylow Theorems. I am a little confused as to how to do this, so any help would be great. Cheers.

Comment: HINT: what are the orders of the elements in the groups?

Comment: What can you say about $|H\cap K|$? (Lagrange)

Comment: Ohhh, does the order of the intersection have to be 1 because the order of H has to divide the order of K? And they're relatively prime so gcd = 1?

Comment: @Cjw123 you got it :)

Comment: thanks @It'sNotALie. May I DM you regarding one more question? it's unrelated to this thread but i'd rather not create a whole new thread

Comment: there's no dm's on stackexchange, just post a question! :)

Comment: Which textbook are you referring to?

Answer (score 3):

Since $H$ and $K$ are both subgroups, so is $H\cap K$ (which is a finite subgroup of the finite subgroups $H$ and $K$). By the Lagrange theorem, the order of $H\cap K$ must divide both $|H|$ and $|K|$. Since the orders of $H$ and $K$ are relatively prime, necessarily $|H\cap K|=1$. Therefore, $H\cap K=\{e\}.$

Answer (score 2):

Since $H,K\le G$, both $H$ and $K$ are groups. (Why?)

---

Note that $H\cap K\le H$ and $H\cap K\le K$.

*Proof:* Without loss of generality, I will show $H\cap K\le H$. I will use the [one-step subgroup test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroup_test#:%7E:text=In%20abstract%20algebra%2C%20the%20one,is%20also%20in%20the%20subset.).

Since $e\in H$ and $e\in K$, we have $e\in H\cap K$, so $H\cap K\neq \varnothing$.

Suppose $r\in H\cap K$. Then, by definition, we have $r\in H$ and $r\in K$, so, in particular, $r\in H$. Hence $H\cap K\subseteq H$.

Suppose $x,y\in H\cap K$. Then $x,y\in H$ and $x,y\in K$, so, since $H, K\le G$, we have $xy^{-1}\in H$ and $xy^{-1}\in K$. Hence $xy^{-1}\in H\cap K$.

Hence $H\cap K\le H$.$\square$

---

Now apply Lagrange's Theorem twice.

Answer (score 0):

Since $H$ and $K$ are finite subgroups of $G$ then $H\cap K$ is also a subgroup of $G$ (because subgroups are closed under intersection) but furthermore, $H\cap K$ is also a subgroup of $H$ and $K$ respectively. So by Lagrange's theorem $|H\cap K|$ must divide $|H|$ and $|K|$, but since $|H|$ and $|K|$ are relatively prime, the only possible value for $|H\cap K|$ is $1$ and every subgroup must contain the identity, hence $H\cap K=\langle e \rangle$.

Answer (score 0):

**Note**

Just a note to add that the answers here assume that the intersection of two subgroups of a group is itself a subgroup which, to me, is not obvious.
Either the question should be amended to say that "You may assume that the intersection of two subgroups of a group is itself a group", or proving that first should be part of the proof.

To see proofs of this assumption see, for example, "[Groups and Symmetry](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Groups-Symmetry-Undergraduate-Texts-Mathematics/dp/0387966757)" by MA Armstrong (pages 23 and 24), or this excellent [hint towards a proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/297356/intersection-of-2-subgroups-must-be-a-subgroup-proof) posted on MSE by @amWhy